# Prove the existence of a regular tetrahedron with some costraints on the center of mass

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

"Prove there exists in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ a regular tetrahedron of real side $d$ such that if one puts in its vertices four strictly positive masses $m_1>m_2>m_3>m_4$ the center of mass is in $(1,2,3)$".
I built an explicit solution, so in a way I answered the question,
but it seems to me a bit like cheating. 
I can't seem to prove the existence of a tetrahedron in general in an elegant fashion. 
Any clue how I might prove it without building an explicit solution and without really lenghty calculations?

Comment: To prove the existence it is enough to find 1 example

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question. Place any regular tetrahedron anywhere. Place the masses. Its cm must be somewhere. Now move it so that its cm moves to the point (1,2,3).